# Spring MVC Flash Attributes

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

How do I enhance the Controller below to utilize Spring MVC's Flash Attributes?  The use case is a copy function.

POST/REQUEST/GET implementation:

1. client clicks "copy" button in the UI
2. server sets the response "Location" header
3. client redirects to "path/to/page?copy"
4. server provides ModelAndView
5. client (jQuery success function) sets window.location

FooController redirect method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "{fooId}", method = POST, params = { "copy" })
@Transactional
@ResponseStatus(CREATED)
public void getCopyfoo(@PathVariable String fooId, 
HttpServletResponse response, RedirectAttributes redirectAttrs) {
    response.setHeader("Location", uriPath);
    //no worky?!:
    redirectAttrs.addFlashAttribute("barKey", "barValue");
}
```

FooController get method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "{fooId}", method = GET)
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public ModelAndView findFooById(@PathVariable String fooId, 
HttpServletRequest request){ 
    Map<String, ?> map = RequestContextUtils.getInputFlashMap(request);
    // map is empty...
    return modelAndViewFromHelperMethod();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm affraid that `RedirectAttributes` work only with `RedirectView`,
so Your controller should return for example:

```
1. String: "redirect:/[uriPath]"
2. new RedirectView([uriPath])
```

If you realy need to handle server response with JS, then maybe handling HTTP status 302 would help.

Comment: Could you add some additional details on how one would handle HTTP status 302?